# not able to start weblogic admin console

Tags: weblogic

On starting the admin console i am getting the below error..

```
<28-Oct-2013 07:38:38 o'clock EDT> <Critical> <Security> <BEA-090470> <Inconsistent   security configuration, the REFSSMNOV security realm has been configured to use security data in deployment descriptors but no DeployableRoleMapper has been configured with deployment enabled.>
<28-Oct-2013 07:38:38 o'clock EDT> <Critical> <Security> <BEA-090470> <Inconsistent security configuration, the REFSSMNOV security realm has been configured to use security data in deployment descriptors but no DeployableAuthorizer has been configured with deployment enabled.>
<28-Oct-2013 07:38:38 o'clock EDT> <Critical> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000362> <Server failed. Reason:

There are 1 nested errors:

weblogic.security.service.SecurityServiceRuntimeException: [Security:090411]Security Realm [REFSSMNOV] improperly configured
    at weblogic.security.service.CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.initializeRealm(CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.java:439)
    at weblogic.security.service.CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.loadRealm(CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.java:840)
    at weblogic.security.service.CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.initializeRealms(CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.java:869)
    at weblogic.security.service.CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.initialize(CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.java:1028)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityServiceManager.initialize(SecurityServiceManager.java:873)
    at weblogic.security.SecurityService.start(SecurityService.java:141)
    at weblogic.t3.srvr.SubsystemRequest.run(SubsystemRequest.java:64)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:528)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:209)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:178)
Caused by: weblogic.management.utils.ErrorCollectionException: [Security:090519]The realm REFSSMNOV is not properly configured. Follow the directions in the following errors to correctly configure the realm.
    [Security:090520]The realm REFSSMNOV does not have an authenticator configured. To correct the problem, configure an authenticator.
    at weblogic.security.internal.RealmValidatorImpl.validate(RealmValidatorImpl.java:53)
    at weblogic.management.security.RealmImpl.validate(RealmImpl.java:54)
    at weblogic.management.security.RealmMBeanImpl.validate(RealmMBeanImpl.java:2635)
    at weblogic.security.service.CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.initializeRealm(CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.java:435)
    ... 9 more
```

not able to find the reason.. all the configurations seems to be correct.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You're not using the default `myrealm` so it sounds like a config step was missed. Have you seen: https://forums.oracle.com/thread/1062343

Answer (score 0):

Go to console, click on security realms

Configure as per your requirement....

Please follow below links for more detailed information

http://onlineappsdba.com/index.php/2008/11/22/security-in-oracle-weblogic-realm-security-provider-authentication-authorization-users/

http://www.packtpub.com/article/weblogic-security-realm